# Add refrence to Iconic.dll (DotNetZip) In My Wix Installer

Tags: c#, dll, reference, wix

I have a program that uses the file 'Ionic.Zip.dll' from DotNetZip Library and I apply installer to this program.

I'm using **DotNetZip**.

Now I cant add a reference for 'Ionic.Zip.dll' to the Wix(installer) project, when i try to add reference I get the following error:

> “A reference to [filepath] could not be added. Please make sure that
>   the file is accessible, and that it is a valid WiX reference.“

I Think Wix only accept a Projects reference and not dll files.

What can I do ? thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It might be easier to help you if you share some code

Comment: Yan I don't think that sharing my code will accomplish anything because i didnt try to add the dll in any form of code writing only by the UI(mouse right click, "add reference" pick my dll, get the error).
so i need to know how could i install my software (using Wix) and add a dll file (maybe add component?) with the installation of my software that my software will know to get it when it runs on the computer(after install of course).
that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I Think Wix only accept a Projects reference and not dll files.

I was waiting for this, since I wasn't sure what you meant by "reference".

When it comes to WiX I find adding references to projects/DLLs to be an *utter pain*. Maybe I'm just bad with them, I'm not sure, but the easiest way I found to add a project (and all of it's dependencies) was to simply make a bunch of `Component` elements, and assign each one a single file from the folder in which the file is being compiled to, see general example below (this is just based off of how I lay out my product.wxs files):

```
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="MainProgramFiles" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <Component Id="FooEXE">
            <File Source="..\Foo\Foo.exe"/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="BarDLL">
            <File Source="..\Foo\Bar.dll"/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="DotNetZipDLL">
            <File Source="..\Foo\DotNetZip.dll"/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="AnotherExampleDLL">
            <File Source="..\Foo\AnotherExample.dll"/>
        </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

NOTE: you'll need to build your **other projects before the WiX files** in order for this to work.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask, I hope this helps.

Comment: Nice man! this is the want i meant...suppose i do it(installed a bounch of dll in my program folder) how my program know to gram the dll from that folder ? i need to configure that(in the actual program project) ?
You understand my question ? (i'm having a hard time explaining myself)

Comment: By default, all DLLs compile to the same folder that you are compiling the main project to, so all files stay together, and foo.exe will look in the folder it is installed to for these DLLs.

Comment: Last thing:
when you wrote:
"you'll need to build your other projects before the WiX files in order for this to work."

you talking about first build my software project and than build the Wix installer project ? i got it right ?